# ¿Como crear un comando del estilo \Cos{} ó \Sin{}?

Tags: latex

Noté que LaTeX no tiene un comando para la cosecante hiperbólica (/csch) ni para la secante hiperbólica (/sech), buscando un tutorial creé los siguientes comandos:

`\newcommand{\sech}{\mathrm{sech} \,}`
`\newcommand{\csch}{\mathrm{csch} \,}`

Pero noté que al usar las expresiones `\sech^2 z` ó `\csch^2 z`, se creaba un espacio entre sech y el ^2 (se puede ver la diferencia con el que si esta definido `\tanh^2{z}`), por la forma en que esta definido el comando lo entiendo, además no es molesto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me interesa ahora incluir en el comando los típicos parentesis que rodean al argumento `z`.
Rehice el comando como:
`\newcommand{\sech}[1]{\mathrm{sech} \, (#1)}` Pero al escribir `\sech^2{z}` sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realmente he intentado cambiar algunos cosas, pero no encuento una forma sencilla de que exista un solo comando igual de funcional como `\sin{z}` al que se le pueda incluir lo parentesis típicos de argumento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que utilices el comando `\DeclareMathOperator` del paquete `amsmath`. Automáticamente establece la tipografía apropiada y espaciados estándar. En tu caso sería algo así:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
```

y luego se usa simplemente con el comando `\sech`. No te recomiendo que le agregues los paréntesis al comando por varios motivos:

1. No sabes si en general el argumento de la secante hiperbólica será de una sola línea (por ejemplo, podrías querer que en alguna expresión esté `\sech(\frac{x}{y})`, en cuyo caso los paréntesis se verán muy pequeños. La alternativa sería poner siempre los paréntesis en la forma `\(` y `\)`, pero no suelen verse bien en modo de párrafo porque son un poco más grandes que los paréntesis normales, aún con texto en modo en línea.
2. Si llegas a necesitar hablar de la función sin un argumento, no podrías hacerlo.
3. Te impediría cambiar de estilo de paréntesis si tienes expresiones anidadas (por ejemplo: `\sech[(x+2)^2 + \cos(3x)]`)